# How can I tell what is the http status code returned by a request to a url?

Tags: http

Is there a way to tell what code is returned by hitting a url?

I tried to look it up, but all I find is a list of different codes. I'm trying to find out the http status code returned for a number of URLs I'm working with, but I don't know where to even start looking for where to find the status codes.

Any assistance pointing me in the right direction would be a big help.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML source code for a web page? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for this. There are literally hundreds of other tools and pluggings to view raw HTTP info.

Comment: @oleksii thanks - where in Firebug can I see the return code?

Comment: Are you looking for the status codes (like 200 OK)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for this. There are literally hundreds of other tools and pluggings to view raw HTTP info.

For example in Mozilla Firebug you can go to *Net* and hit F5 (refresh the page)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use Chrome browser. Hit F12 to get developer tools and look at the network tab. Shows you all status codes, whether page was from cache etc.